# Incorrect output of double

Tags: c, output, double

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAX_INPUT_NUM 99999.999999
#define NUMBER_OF_SIDES 3


void perimeter(double, double, double, double *, double *);
double square(double, double, double, double);
void heights(double, double, double, double *, double *, double *, double);
void medians(double, double, double, double *, double *, double *);
void bisectors(double, double, double, double *, double *, double *, double);

int main()
{
    char buffer[14]; 
    double first_side = 0;
    double second_side = 0;
    double third_side = 0;
    
    double per = 0;
    double semi_per = 0;
    
    double height_to_firstside = 0;
    double height_to_secondside = 0;
    double height_to_thirdside = 0;
    
    double median_to_firstside = 0;
    double median_to_secondside = 0;
    double median_to_thirdside = 0;
    
    double bisector_to_firstside = 0;
    double bisector_to_secondside = 0;
    double bisector_to_thirdside = 0;
    
    printf("You have certain limitations!\nYou can use only numbers from 0.0001 to 99999.999999 and only 12 symbols in a num\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_SIDES; i++) 
    {
        printf("Enter a number for side %d: ", i + 1);
        fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin); //Зчитуємо рядок
        
        if (strspn(buffer, "0123456789.") != strlen(buffer) - 1) 
        {
            printf("Invalid input. Please enter other nums.\n");
            return 0;
        }
        
        int dot_count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(buffer); j++)
        {
            if (buffer[0] == '0' && buffer[1] != '.' || buffer[0] == '.')
            {
                printf("Invalid input. Please enter other nums.\n");
                return 0;
            }
            
            if (buffer[j] == '.')
            {
                dot_count++;
            }
            
            if (dot_count >= 2)
            {
                printf("Invalid input. Please enter other nums.\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }

        fflush(stdin);
        
        double input = 0;
        sscanf(buffer, "%lf", &input); //Виймаємо з рядка %lf

        if (i == 0) 
        {
            first_side = input;
        }
        else if (i == 1)
        {
            second_side = input;
        }
        else if (i == 2)
        {
            third_side = input;
        }
        fflush(stdin);
    }

    
    if ((first_side + second_side) < third_side  (second_side + third_side) < first_side  (first_side + third_side) < second_side)
    {
        printf("Unreal triangle, enter other nums\n");
        return 0;
    }
    
    if (first_side < 0.0001)
    {
        first_side = 0;
    }
    
    if (second_side < 0.0001)
    {
        second_side = 0;
    }
    
    if (third_side < 0.0001)
    {
        third_side = 0;
    }
    
    if (first_side > MAX_INPUT_NUM  second_side > MAX_INPUT_NUM  third_side > MAX_INPUT_NUM)
    {
        printf("Invalid num. Follow limitations!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    
    if (first_side == 0  second_side == 0  third_side == 0)
    {
        printf("Invalid num, enter other nums\n");
        return 0;
    }

    perimeter(first_side, second_side, third_side, &per, &semi_per);
    double area = square(first_side, second_side, third_side, semi_per);
    heights(first_side, second_side, third_side, &height_to_firstside, &height_to_secondside, &height_to_thirdside, semi_per);
    medians(first_side, second_side, third_side, &median_to_firstside, &median_to_secondside, &median_to_thirdside);
    bisectors(first_side, second_side, third_side, &bisector_to_firstside, &bisector_to_secondside, &bisector_to_thirdside, semi_per);
printf("Perimeter: %.10lf\n", per);
    printf("Semi-perimeter: %.11lf\n", semi_per);
    
    printf("Square: %.12lf\n", area);
    
    printf("Height for the first side: %.12lf\n", height_to_firstside);
    printf("Height for the second side: %.12lf\n", height_to_secondside);
    printf("Height for the third side: %.12lf\n", height_to_thirdside);
    
    printf("Median for the first side: %.12lf\n", median_to_firstside);
    printf("Median for the second side: %.12lf\n", median_to_secondside);
    printf("Median for the third side: %.12lf\n", median_to_thirdside);
    
    printf("Bisector for the first side: %.12lf\n", bisector_to_firstside);
    printf("Bisector for the second side: %.12lf\n", bisector_to_secondside);
    printf("Bisector for the third side: %.12lf\n", bisector_to_thirdside);

    return 0;
}

void perimeter(double first, double second, double third, double *pPer1, double *pPer2)
{
    *pPer1 = first + second + third;
    *pPer2 = *pPer1 / 2.0;
}

double square(double first, double second, double third, double semi_perimeter)
{
    double square_size;
    square_size = sqrt(semi_perimeter * (semi_perimeter - first) * (semi_perimeter - second) * (semi_perimeter - third));

    return square_size;
}

void heights(double first, double second, double third, double *pHeight_firstside, double *pHeight_secondside, double *pHeight_thirdside, double semi_perimeter)
{
    *pHeight_firstside = 2.0 * (sqrt(semi_perimeter * (semi_perimeter - first) * (semi_perimeter - second) * (semi_perimeter - third))) / first;
    *pHeight_secondside = 2.0 * (sqrt(semi_perimeter * (semi_perimeter - first) * (semi_perimeter - second) * (semi_perimeter - third))) / second;
    *pHeight_thirdside = 2.0 * (sqrt(semi_perimeter * (semi_perimeter - first) * (semi_perimeter - second) * (semi_perimeter - third))) / third;
}

void medians(double first, double second, double third, double *pMedian_firstside, double *pMedian_secondside, double *pMedian_thirdside)
{
    *pMedian_firstside = 0.5 * (sqrt((2.0 * second * second) + (2.0 * third * third) - (first * first)));
    *pMedian_secondside = 0.5 * (sqrt((2.0 * first * first) + (2.0 * third * third) - (second * second)));
    *pMedian_thirdside = 0.5 * (sqrt((2.0 * first * first) + (2.0 * second * second) - (third * third)));
}

void bisectors(double first, double second, double third, double *pBisector_firstside, double *pBisector_secondside, double *pBisector_thirdside, double semi_perimeter)
{
    *pBisector_firstside = (2.0 / (second + third)) * (sqrt((second * third * semi_perimeter) * (semi_perimeter - first)));
    *pBisector_secondside = (2.0 / (first + third)) * (sqrt((first * third * semi_perimeter) * (semi_perimeter - second)));
    *pBisector_thirdside = (2.0 / (first + second)) * (sqrt((first * second * semi_perimeter) * (semi_perimeter - third)));
}
```

**Problem**

This code takes the sides of a triangle from the user, then calculates the perimeter, square, heights, medians and bisectors. As you can see, all the data that is output has the *double data type*.
So, the problem lies in the incorrect output of data on large or small values.

*Example*:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PW3e.png)

As you can see that
*median to the first side = second and third side that is incorrect,*
*semi perimeter has 6 on the end that is impossible*

**What I tried**

Firstly, I did this program on float data type and faced with this problem.
Then I started using double data type for greater accuracy, but problem was still the same.

After that I increased the number of digits after the dot `%.12lf`, but problem stayed.

[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5npQ7.png)

[Output with less accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aCe1.png)
`%.6lf`

[Output with greater accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PX5BK.png)
`%.12lf`

[WolframAlpha Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z20wi.png)
It is the result of calculation of height to the first side, but from **WolframAlpha**.

Comment: That last 6 is at the limits of the precision of `double`. You just have to accept [Why Are Floating Point Numbers Inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate) Only a finite set of discrete values can be exactly represented. The infinite number of other values have to represented by the nearest one of these. Floating point is not very kind to decimal arithmetic.

Comment: Unrelated: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined in Linux, and you don't need it here anyway.

Comment: The input value `0.0001000001` cannot be exactly represented by binary floating point encoding.

Comment: Please post text as text. Please do not post links to external sites with images of text.

Comment: The compiler rejects this line `if ((first_side + second_side) < third_side  (second_side + third_side) < first_side  (first_side + third_side) < second_side)`. Something went wrong with posting/pasting the code.

Comment: `printf` `"%.12lf"` format is wrong for `double`. It has to be `"%.12f"`

Comment: Wofram Alpha is just showing random digits. If you input 10 digit numbers, you just cannot magically get 30 digits precision in the result.

Comment: @pmg To be precise: UB *anywhere*...

Comment: Well @Aconcagua, Microsoft defines the behaviour for their library (I remember there used to be a note about it being UB everywhere else) -- see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fflush?view=msvc-170 "... If the stream was opened in read mode [...] the call to fflush has no effect ..."

Comment: @pmg OK, MS once more cooking their own soup... Then: *'anywhere else'* ;)

Comment: @pmg Actually POSIX seems to [well-define](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush), [too](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fflush.html) (???). Irritates me somehow…

Comment: LOL At least C23 ([n3096](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3096.pdf) 7.23.5.2) keeps it UB! Maybe `fflush(stdin)` will get a definition in next Standard (`fflsuh(stdin)` defined as doing nothing)

Comment: OT: Please don't copy/paste/adapt code. All of the calculating functions could be made trivial (and readable) by calculating one or a few _intermediate_ results. Don't force the reader to validate a morass of code. **DRY**